# Scrapy fixed URLs

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Trying to wrap my head around this... I have a fixed list of 100,000 URLs I would like to scrape, which is fine, I know how to handle that. But first I need to get a cookie from an initial form post and use it for the subsequent requests. Would that be like a nested spider? Just trying to understand the architecture for that use case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scrapy will do the cookies things automatically.

All you need to do is form post first, then yield the requests for your 100,000 URLs.

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "myspider"
    start_urls = (
        'https://example.com/login', #login page
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.url_list = [] #your url lists
        return super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def parse(self, response):
        data = {}

        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata=data,
            callback=self.my_start_requests
        )

    def my_start_requests(self, response):
        # ignore the login callback response
        for url in self.url_list:
            # scrapy will take care the cookies
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_item, dont_filter=True)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        # your code here
        pass
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. Thanks a million! I need to edit your code slightly for syntax but its spot on.